# The function does not apear in the OnClick() unity button UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void ButtonClickHandler()
    {
        Debug.Log("Button Clicked!");
    }
}
```

My `Onclick` doesn't work in Unity.

Even when I added my example script to the none object part my functions don't appear:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did unity compile the code , are you using some tool like fast script reload ? or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you drag a script directly from the project into the field in the button?

You want to attach your Example script to a GameObject first, and then drag and drop that game object into the OnClick field. Then you'll get more options in the dropdown, and you can find your function there under Example/ButtonClickHandler ()